# Syntax errors but compiles successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have many many syntax errors but my solution and project compile just fine. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Why would you provide information as image which can be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Comment: @marcelocano  try to organize it better and put it in text

Answer (score 1):

Your error is above that part you have showed us.. 
The part of it compiling I think it's using the last correct build.

Comment: Can you add any thing more?

Answer (score 1):

This can be because of couple of reasons.

1) First this is this might be due to having some issues with building a library, but taking the last successful build's dlls, so that no compile errors is shown and the build is success.
To check this you can do a 'clean solution' first.

However, do you mean you don't see 'Clean Solution' option? It should be there when you right click on the solution, but anyhow you can do a 'Rebuild' too, so that it will clean and build again for you.

2) Sometimes, this can be due to Visual Studio issue as well and to check that, you can simply restart VS and retry. I have some experiences like this and after trying with many other ways, restarting VS helped to solve the problem.

3) Finally, go with a Windows restart (It's Windows at the end of the day and many problems could be solved with this step ! :))

Good luck !

Comment: this error of blue line apper actually in commented lines T_T

Comment: but my solution and proyect compiled succefully I dont know what happens

Comment: @marcelocano but, did you try the steps I've mentioned above?